# Clang-format option. Initializator end brace

Tags: clang-format

We need an option that would wrap the trailing curly brace of the initializer to a new line, in case of multiple parameters:

```cpp
SomeStruct a{
  .i = 1,
  .f = 2.2};
```

vs

```cpp
SomeStruct a{
  .i = 1,
  .f = 2.2
};
```

In this case, the initializer with one parameter remains on the same line:

```cpp
SomeStruct a{.i = 1};
```

Answer (score 0):

The intended solution is to leave a trailing comma in order to achieve what you're looking for, for example:

```cpp
SomeStruct a{
  .i = 1,
  .f = 2.2};
```

under default options, will become:

```cpp
SomeStruct a{.i = 1, .f = 2.2};
```

but adding a trailing comma:

```cpp
SomeStruct a{
  .i = 1,
  .f = 2.2,
};
```

under default options, will leave this example as is.